# How to make an Array of images getting by input field and display the Array image as slider

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, arraylist, display

My problem is to make array of image by input field and display array images as slider in JavaScript
anyone can solve it please answer me

Please give code of JavaScript

```
    document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("change", function(){
           const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
                   localStorage.setItem("recent-image", reader.result)
              });
           reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded()", ()=> {
        
        const imageurl = localStorage.getItem("recent-image");

        if(imageurl){
            document.querySelector("#b").setAttribute("src", imageurl);
        }
    });
```

can you do this in array please answer me

it take only one image image but, I want to store multiple image in local storage by array
please answer me

Comment: This is because localStorage stores data as string value. You'll need to serialize multiple image in a single key (recent-image is your current key) or use multiple keys for your multiple images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see is to define your localstorage and make sure that the images are stored in it to later go through each one of them, I leave an example of how to solve it

```
var images = localStorage.getItem('images') || [];

function saveImages() {
    localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(images));
}

function drawImages() {
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    slider.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const img = images[i];
        const html_img = document.createElement('img');
        html_img.src = img;
        html_img.alt = 'Alt img';
        html_img.width = 200;
        html_img.height = 150;
        slider.appendChild(html_img);
    }
}

document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("change", function(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
        images.push(reader.result);
        drawImages();
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded()", drawImages);
```